# C# DynamoDB complex type IList<T> converter

Tags: c#, list, amazon-web-services, converters, amazon-dynamodb

I need to add an `IList<MyCustomType>` as a `DynamoDBProperty` into a DynamoDB table whose items are defined by the class `MyTableItem`.

Using information from this [AWS Documentation page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBContext.ArbitraryDataMapping.html), I implemented the converter for `MyCustomType` (not for `IList<MyCustomType>`).
But when creating a new `MyTableItem` I noticed that the `ToEntry()` method receive as parameter an object of type `IList<MyCustomType>` and not `MyCustomType`.

Reading the documentation I had understood that the lists (`List` or `IList`, or collections in general) was automatically handled by DynamoDB...

How can I achieve the desired result?

This is the code:

```
// MyTableItem
[Serializable]
public class MyTableItem
{
    [DynamoDBHashKey]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBProperty]
    public string Field1 { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBProperty]
    public string Field2 { get; set; }

    // List of MyCustomType objects
    [DynamoDBProperty(typeof(MyCustomTypeConverter))]
    public IList<MyCustomType> CustomField { get; set; }
}

// MyCustomType
[Serializable]
public class MyCustomType
{
    public string DocumentType { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

// Converter methods
public class MyCustomTypeConverter : IPropertyConverter
{
    public DynamoDBEntry ToEntry(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return new Primitive { Value = null };

        MyCustomType item = value as MyCustomType;
        if (item == null)
            throw new InvalidCastException("Cannot convert MyCustomType to DynamoDBEntry.");

        string data = string.Format("{0};{1};{2}", item.DocumentType, item.Status, item.Code);

        DynamoDBEntry entry = new Primitive { Value = data };

        return entry;
    }

    public object FromEntry(DynamoDBEntry entry)
    {
        if (entry == null)
            return new MyCustomType();

        Primitive primitive = entry as Primitive;
        if (primitive == null || !(primitive.Value is string) || string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)primitive.Value))
            throw new InvalidCastException("Cannot convert DynamoDBEntry to MyCustomType.");

        string[] data = ((string)(primitive.Value)).Split(new string[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        if (data.Length != 3)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Invalid arguments number.");

        MyCustomType complexData = new MyCustomType
        {
            DocumentType = Convert.ToString(data[0]),
            Status = Convert.ToString(data[1]),
            Code = Convert.ToString(data[2])
        };

        return complexData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

It seems that the DynamoDb SDK has no problem *serializing* `IList<T>`, it does have trouble *deserializing*.  Just speculation, but this is probably because it doesn't know which concrete type to use.

I had a similar setup to yours, and I tried changing my documents to use `List<T>` and the SDK was able to deserialize without adding any custom `IPropertyConverter` implementations.

It looks like the full two-way support is only there if you expose a concrete List instead of the interface.  So that's one possible way out of the problem.

But if you want to try to solve the problem of the `IList` I would work with what the SDK is actually sending you, the `IList`, not the items from the list.   To me it would make sense to iterate over that list and convert each item into a list of entries.  For deserialization you'll get that collection of entries back, and you can build up a new list of your models.

TL;DR use a list if you can, otherwise implement your converter against the `IList<T>` not `T`.